# Multiple actions in Routing config, nothing helps

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have ApiController called Users
And on default I have Post in there.
It works fine.

However, I decided to add an additional action that also works on Post method, and now I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(dynamic data){}

[HttpPost]
public HttpRequestMessage LogOff([FromBody]dynamic data){}
```

I also modified Routing, trying every commented here option:
    //config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    //    name: "UserApi",
    //    routeTemplate: "api/Users/LogOff/{data}/{id}",
    //    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    //);

```
//config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
//    name: "userapi",
//    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
//);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "DefaultApi",
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I also played with switching their order position and no result, it always says : web api Multiple actions were found that match....

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is: it's impossible to mix Noname actions (like standard Post) and named Post Actions.
As an example I created 2 named actions which work both on Post and they work fine, however the original Post stopped working...
It's weird because routing is correct and I have options for both: with and without {action}

Answer (score 0):

In the next link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/624180/Routing-Basics-in-ASP-NET-Web-API) you have the explanation why this is not working. I am going to show you the part that explains why your code is not working:

> Unlike the familiar MVC route template, the Web API template does not
>   specify an {action} route parameter. This is because, as we mentioned
>   earlier, the Web API framework will by default map incoming requests
>   to the appropriate action based upon the HTTP verb of the request.

So you cannot have two methods using the same verb (in this case POST) with the same parameters.

A solution if you want to implement it, would be using attribute routing. The next code is an example of that:

```
[RoutePrefix("users")]
public class UsersController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("post")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post(dynamic data){}

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("logoff")]
    public HttpRequestMessage LogOff([FromBody]dynamic data){}

}
```

If you are going to use this solution, you have to add this line of code in you WebApiConfig.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

I hope that it helps.